# Disable TouchableHighlight onPress?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to disable groups of TouchableHighlight if one of them pressed ? Is it possible ? For example I have listview and each row has two TouchableHighlights. If one of them pressed, I want to disable onPress function of these two touchables.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. Here is how:

First, thanks to [James Ide](https://github.com/ide) for awesome [button](https://github.com/ide/react-native-button) component with [`disabled`](https://github.com/ide/react-native-button/blob/master/Button.js#L19) props.

I wrote custom component --`main.js`-- for button group. And use `disabled` props for disable button group.

[image: screenshot and logs]

`index.ios.js`:

```
class PNTest extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state ={
      clicked: []
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Main handleClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)} left={1} right={2} name={'group1'}/>
        <Main handleClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)} left={3} right={4} name={'group2'}/>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          {this.state.clicked}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _handleClick(id, group){
    this.state.clicked.push(id);
    console.log(group + ' now inactive and clicked button id: ' + id);
    console.log('clicked button ids: ' + this.state.clicked);
  }
}
```

`main.js`:

```
class Main extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      disabled: false,
      left: {},
      right: {}
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
          disabled={this.state.disabled}
          style={[styles.buttonContainer, this.state.left]}
          onPress={() => this._onPress(this.props.left)}>
          Left
        </Button>
        <Button
          disabled={this.state.disabled}
          style={[styles.buttonContainer,this.state.right]}
          onPress={() => this._onPress(this.props.right)}>
          Right
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _onPress(id){
    var left = {};
    var right = {};

    if(id === this.props.left){
      left = styles.buttonSelected;
      right = styles.buttonNotSelected;
    }else if(id === this.props.right){
      right = styles.buttonSelected;
      left = styles.buttonNotSelected;
    }

    this.setState({
      disabled: true,
      left: left,
      right: right
    });

    this.props.handleClick(id, this.props.name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

One option here is to use a very basic semaphore. Once one of the buttons is clicked, you can set a global variable x to true. And in the other onPress function, you can return if x is true

```
onPressOne(){
 if(this.semaphore)
   return
 this.semaphore = true
 // other code here
}
onPressTwo(){
 if(this.semaphore)
   return
 this.semaphore = true
 // other code here
}
```

The buttons will not do anything until you reset `this.semaphore = false`
If you want to disable the visual highlight from the TouchableHighlight, you can change the **activeOpacity** property when one of the button is clicked

Comment: I don't get it. Each row has same component, lets say `<Button />`, and Button component has two touchable. how to handle which rows disabled and others are active. If I send props like this `<Button isActive={this.semaphore} />` all rows will be disable.